# Is there a default value, Unix timestamp, for column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unix-timestamp

I don't know why, but I like to work with Unix-timestamp. Maybe because I need to perform calculations with time like with number, e.g. time()-604800.

Right now I have integer column whereto I insert result of time(). I think it isn't right way, is it? Is there a default value -- unix timestamp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should get rid of the habit of using unix timestamps in your database. PostgreSQL has [really awesome date functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) such as `datetimecol - interval '1 week'`. It can also easily convert to unix timestamps using `extract(epoch from datetimecol)`.

Anyway, you can use `extract(epoch from now())` as the default value of your column.

Comment: I think it's from MySQL, before I've been using it and I didn't like time functions in it. And recently I've decided that MySQL doesn't fit my needs and I've chose PgSql. :)

Comment: Guessed so. Take it as a reason to get away from bad habits. In case you are using PHP also start using PDO or at least [`pg_query_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) instead of escaping.

Comment: Be sure to use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE (also known as timestamptz); the default TIMESTAMP (which is "WITHOUT TIME ZONE") does not represent a moment in time.